# View uncommitted changes to a specific file with git

Tags: git

How do I see uncommitted changes that have been made to a specific file with git? I have tried

```
git diff
```

but I get all of the changes of the entire repo. When I tried

```
git diff <filename>
```

I got

`fatal: ambiguous argument 'style1.css': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions`

so then I tried

`git diff -- <filename>`

with the same result.

Answer (score 5):

Turns out the file was in a directory that I didn't expect and the error message was correct. This works as expected.

`git diff </path/and/file/name>`